# Не импортируется executor из библиотеки aiogram в python

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

```py
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram import Dispatcher
from aiogram import types
from aiogram import executor

token = " "

bot = Bot(token)

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Почему не импортируется `executor` из `aiogram`?

**ОШИБКА**

> ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\Asl\PycharmProjects\pybot.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram_*init*_.py)*

Comment: Потому что его там нет. У вас код по версию 2, а установлен aiogram 3

Comment: @CausonQ КОД ВЕРСИИ 2 ЭТО ВЫ ИМЕЕТЕ ВВИДУ PYTHON ВЕРСИИ  2 ??

Comment: aiogram у вас какой версии? `pip show aiogram` введите. И используйте [документацию по aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/).

Comment: Нет, скорее всего @CausonQ имеет в виду версию aiogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executor есть только на версии aiogram 2.х. Проверьте, скачали ли вы правильную версию. Попробуйте ввести в терминал:

```
pip uninstall aiogram
pip install aiogram==2.25.2
```

Comment: у меня ошибки 
*
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
*
Это из-за того что у меня версия pyhton 3.12.1 ?

Comment: Нет. Это из-за того, что у вас aiogram 3.x.x. Используйте aiogram 2.25.2. Если все равно эта ошибка, то переустановите pip

Comment: переустановил pip, далее хотел установить aiogram версию 2.25.2 и мне выдает ошибки:

**note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-note-this-error-originates-from-subprocess
Здесь подробно рассказывают об этой проблеме

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример запуска бота в aiogram3.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
# Объект бота
bot = Bot(token="12345678:AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh")
# Диспетчер
dp = Dispatcher()

# Хэндлер на команду /start
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Hello!")

# Запуск процесса поллинга новых апдейтов
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```