# ошибка aiogram python в тг боте

Tags: python, aiogram

```
вот ошибкаTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\tgbot\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aiogram import executor, Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py):
вот сам код:
  import openai
from aiogram import executor, Dispatcher

# Установите ваш токен бота и ключ API для ChatGPT
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = '####'
OPENAI_API_KEY = '####'

# Инициализируйте ключ API для ChatGPT
openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY

# Инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Функция для общения с ChatGPT
def generate_chatgpt_response(user_message):
    prompt = f"User: {user_message}\nChatGPT: "
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=150
    )
    return response['choices'][0]['text']

# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Я бот. Чем могу помочь?")

# Обработчик входящих текстовых сообщений
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def handle_text(message: types.Message):
    user_message = message.text
    response = generate_chatgpt_response(user_message)
    await message.reply(response)

# Запуск бота
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Если ключи в коде `TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN` и `OPENAI_API_KEY` настоящие, советую Вам их обновить (reset/refresh), иначе другие пользователи смогут воспользоваться ими в нежелательным для Вас образом! Следует использовать `environment variables` для таких целей! Хоть модератор удалил их из вопроса, их все ещё можно просмотреть в списке изменения, будьте осторожны и замените токены!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T, я не модератор) У меня только есть права редактирования вопросов и я ими воспользовался, чтобы не допустить использования токенов в преступных целях.

Comment: ```pip install aiogram==2.25.2```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не импортируется executor из библиотеки aiogram в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560452/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-executor-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-aiogram-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 0):

У вас код под версию aiogram2, а установлен aiogram 3. Установите версию 2.9 или ниже.